# Rails 3.2 flotilla

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts

we have some problems with upgrading our app to 3.2.

since rails 3.2 **flotilla** doesn't work anymore.

```
undefined method 'chart' for #<#<Class:0x00000006f08fb0>:0x000000078b7c00>
```

https://github.com/joshuamiller/flotilla/blob/master/lib/flotilla.rb

i cant access a method without self. in modules!? its new in rails 3.2?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the introduction of the asset pipeline in 3.1, there are some changes in the [initialization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html). Because of this, the helper never includes the correct module and thus the method is not available to your views.

To solve this problem I created a proper gem that wraps Flotilla and is compatible with the asset pipeline. You can find it at https://github.com/hnnsgstfssn/flotilla-rails.